# Adding a ner from another pretrained model to a blank model including static vectors

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3

I am very new to Spacy so this question might be kinda dumb, but I can't figure out how to add a NER from an existing model to a blank model.
I am following this example: https://spacy.io/api/language#add_pipe
and this is my code:

```
# Build main nlp
main_nlp = spacy.blank("es-419")

# Get spanish ner
spanish_nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_lg")
main_nlp.add_pipe("ner",source=spanish_nlp, name="spanish_ner")

test_text = # Random text
main_nlp(test_text)
```

I get the following error:
RuntimeError: [E896] There was an error using the static vectors. Ensure that the vectors of the vocab are properly initialized, or set 'include_static_vectors' to False.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to fix it, although I am not sure if it is correct. I added the line

```
main_nlp.vocab.vectors = spanish_nlp.vocab.vectors
```

before adding the pipe and now the error doesn't show up anymore

Comment: This should work fine. Another option would be to pass `spanish_nlp.vocab` into `spacy.blank` as in `spacy.blank("es", vocab=spanish_nlp.vocab)` which copies the whole vocab including the vectors.